# Square grid in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I create a responsive grid of squares in Bootstrap 4?

I know I can create a grid with

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; color: red"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; color: red"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; color: red"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; color: red"></div>
</div>
```

but instead of setting the width and height to 100px, I want the size to be responsive so I can fill out the entire page with grids and keep a small margin between the items.

So I guess I need to define a minimum and maximum size for the items, so I can make the grid define the optimal number of items on each page.

I guess it can be done with flexbox in Bootstrap 4, but I don't find any examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a solution from this page content.

[How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)